# C# get all forms in webbrowser, check price and click button

Tags: c#, forms

I'm a beginner. I hope someone will help me.
How to find forms in webbrowser.

In my webbrowser i have 10 forms.
small example.

```
<form action="#">
<div>Price: 1000</div>
<input type="submit" value="buy">
</form>

<form action="#">
<div>Price: 2000</div>
<input type="submit" value="buy">
</form>
```

Problem is, how to click `buy` button if `price < 1000` with only this form. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Are you using a webbrowser control in a windows forms applicaiton?

Comment: yes :) I use windows form application, and webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but it will work

```
$("form").each(function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).find("div").text().substring(7, 11)) > 1000) {
        alert("Sumbit form here");
        //$(this).submit;
    }
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e82FP/)